# Signin with apple in Apple TV

Tags: ios, tvos, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to implement Sign In With Apple in Apple TV. The moment I click on "Sign In", I get a screen that says "A notification has been sent to nearby devices that are signed in with apple Id". However I have 2 issues here

1. The notification is too slow, it takes more than 10 minutes for me to get a notification. I have both my wifi and bluetooth on, still I face the issue.
2. Even when notification arrives, nothing happens on click of notification.

Any suggestion or solution would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Recently, I'm develop an app using "Sign in with Apple" service. For the first times, it worked. But some days later, when I try to sign in, I get notification to my iPhone, but when I tap on that notification, nothing happened, nothing showed. I don't know why. Please tell me if you're still using this service in your app, does it still work?